# IDP-initiated Single Sign-On POST Binding with SimpleSAMLphp

Tags: php, saml, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I am trying to setup idp for our provided sp through simplesamlphp to achieve this : http://saml.xml.org/wiki/idp-initiated-single-sign-on-post-binding

something i need to do

1. add custom attribute
2. Its generating signature value and digest value randomly i have to give these fixed values
3. Its sending in post variable SamlRequest but i have to send that in SamlResponse variable

   If someone has done it before please help me in this as soon as possible, thanks in advance for considering my question in your valuable time.